# Prove the inequality: $\frac{79}{160}<\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{1-x^4}<\frac{79}{40\sqrt{15}}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

I kinda solved it with the upper and lower integral but don't know if there is a better way. Any hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the lower bound notice that $1-x^4 < \sqrt{1-x^4}$ between $0$ and $1/2$. Taking the integral on the interval will give the lower bound $79/160$. For the upper bound notice that $\sqrt{1-x^4}< 1$ so you can bound your integral from above by $1/2$. This proves the result.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Find the Taylor series expansion for the the term $\sqrt{1-x^4}$ and start evaluating the integral.

Solution:
$\displaystyle \tag*{} \sqrt{1-x^4} = 1 - \dfrac{x^4}{2} - \dfrac{x^8}{8} - \dfrac{x^{12}}{16}\cdots$

Now we have:
$\displaystyle \tag*{} \int \limits _{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}\sqrt{1-x^4} = \int \limits _{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}1 - \dfrac{x^4}{2} - \dfrac{x^8}{8} - \dfrac{x^{12}}{16}\cdots$
and
$\displaystyle \tag*{}\int \limits _{0}^{\frac{1}{2}}1 - \dfrac{x^4}{2} - \dfrac{x^8}{8} - \dfrac{x^{12}}{16}\cdots = \begin{bmatrix} x - \dfrac{x^5}{10} - \dfrac{x^9}{72} - \dfrac{x^{13}}{208}\cdots\\  
\end{bmatrix}_{0}^{\frac{1}{2}} $

If you substitute $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and notice that , $\ x - \dfrac{x^5}{10}$ itself is around $0.496876$ and remaining terms are extremely small so entire sum will be clearly greater than $0.495$

Now, if you see that $\dfrac{79}{160} = 0.49375$, so this is lesser than integral. And $\dfrac{79}{40 \sqrt{15}} \approx 0.51$ which again is greater than the integral.